How to forward requests made to docker container to http.server running inside the container using compose or Dockerfile configuration?
I have the following python code to create a server. The prints are triggered when the server is run up outside a docker container but not when inside a container. I'd like to setup port forwarding and other needed settings in either compose.yaml and/or DockerFile. I don't want to do it via docker commands.
import http.server
import socketserver
import requests
import os

tcp_host = 'localhost'
PORT = 8005
file_storage_host = 'file-storage'#int(os.environ['FILE_STORAGE_HOST'])
file_storage_port = 80#int(os.environ['FILE_STORAGE_PORT'])

class VideoHTTPRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def do_GET(self):
        print('10')
        if self.path == '/video':
            print('3')
            return ''
        else:
            print('4')

Handler = VideoHTTPRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer((tcp_host, PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print(f"tcp server configured to: http://{tcp_host}:{PORT}")
    httpd.serve_forever()

Here's my compose.yaml code
services:
  video-streaming:
    image: video-streaming
    build:
      context: ./video-streaming
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: video-streaming
    ports:
      - 4004:8005
    environment:
      - PORT=80
      - FILE_STORAGE_HOST = file-storage
      - FILE_STORAGE_PORT = 80
    restart: "no"

and my dockerfile


ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.12.3
FROM python:${PYTHON_VERSION}-slim as base


ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app


ARG UID=10001
RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "/nonexistent" \
    --shell "/sbin/nologin" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "${UID}" \
    appuser


RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache/pip \
    --mount=type=bind,source=requirements.txt,target=requirements.txt \
    python -m pip install -r requirements.txt


USER appuser


COPY server.py .

# Expose the port that the application listens on.
EXPOSE 8005

# Run the application.
CMD python server.py

I get the functionality I want when running the python script on its own but not when it's inside a docker container. When spinning up the container it seems to spin up the server ok but it seems no requests are being received by the container. I assume that the problem is that when I go to http://localhost:4004/ on my browser the request isn't forwarded to the TCPServer running inside the container. I've understood that the only thing needed to forward the requests made outside the container to the server running inside the container is port forwarding - so the server host name shouldn't matter. I think I'm doing port forwarding correctly in the compose.yaml file by mapping the external port 4004 to the internal port 8005.

PORT = 8000 ...    socketserver.TCPServer((tcp_host, PORT)  ... - 4004:8005 so what makes you think the app is listening on 8005?

Also setting tcp_host = 'localhost' means the server will be unreachable from outside its own container; that needs to be set to 0.0.0.0.  See for example Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip.  You need to make that change, and change the second ports: value to ...:8000 to match the actual server process's port.

Thanks guys, the 8000 was a typo when posting the question. Changing host to 0.0.0.0 fixed the issue - didn't know localhost behaved in such a way.

As David Maze pointed out in the comments, each docker container has its own localhost that can't be accessed outside the container. Using 0.0.0.0 as the host solved the issue.
